# How do I know whether my SyncAdapter (addPeriodicSync) registered in Android or not?

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I am testing `SyncAdapter` with `addPeriodicSync` with 1 hour interval. Can I check it whether it's registered successfully or not in Android (I am not using emulator)? Because waiting 1 hour just to know it works or not is really wasting time.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a connected device/emulator, you can verify it using adb command,

```
adb shell dumpsys content <package name>
```

This provides all the sync adapters registered and information about whether the sync adapter is enabled, when is the next scheduled period for the sync to run, sync history...

Also, if your sync account is added for the first time, SyncAdapter performs an initial sync immediately. You need not wait for 1 hour (https://catinean.com/2014/08/09/a-curious-case-of-syncadapter-syncing/)